# How to set the taborder for the Datatemplate textboxes in a listbox item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

I have a `ListBox` in my WPF application where i am generating  my `ListBox` items using a `Datatemplate` so in my `Datatemplate` i have some textboxes where i want taborder for Textboxes, How to achieve this i tried many ways but of no use.

Below is my `XAML` code :-

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1" >

    <Grid Height="100" Width="1255" Background="#FFDA4F4F" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue"  Margin="0,-8,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
            <Canvas Background="#F5F5F5" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,31,0,0" x:Name="canvas45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92">        
                <TextBox Canvas.Left="5"  TabIndex="13" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue" Text="{Binding Name}"   Canvas.Top="5" Height="20" Tag="{Binding}" LostFocus="txbbox1LostFocus"   x:Name="txbbox1" Width="82" PreviewTextInput="txbbbox1_PreviewTextInput" Background="Red" />        
            </Canvas>

            <Canvas  Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,31,186,0" x:Name="canvas46" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92">        
                <TextBox Canvas.Top="5"   TabIndex="14" Height="20"  x:Name="txbbox2" LostFocus="txbbox2LostFocus"   Text="{Binding txbbox2}"  Tag="{Binding}" PreviewTextInput="txbbox2_PreviewTextInput" Width="82" Canvas.Left="5" Background="red" />        
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is my listbox which i'm binding with my datatemplate.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1"  Background="Transparent"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="53,430,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1241" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}"  BorderBrush="{x:Null}"   Style="{DynamicResource JListBox1}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBox1_ItemContainerStyle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectionChanged="ListBox1_SelectionChanged"  />
```

Please Give me any suggestion how to do it, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Setting TabIndex for each TextBox inside DataTemplate, try to Set **TabNavigation** to **Cycle** Mode, this will Move he cursor to next focusable field automatically.

Please follow this Link for More details
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25152.wpf-how-to-tab-between-items-in-a-listbox.aspx